# How to convert hex string to Java string?

Tags: java, string, hex

For logging purpose we are converting the logs to byte array and then to hex string. I want to get it back in a Java String, but I am not able to do so.

The hex string in log file looks something like

```
fd00000aa8660b5b010006acdc0100000101000100010000
```

How can I decode this?

Answer (score 76):

Using [`Hex`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) in Apache Commons:

```
String hexString = "fd00000aa8660b5b010006acdc0100000101000100010000";    
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray());
System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Hex is now part of Apache Commons Codec

Comment: Here the dependency: ```<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>```

Comment: It doesn’t need much to recognize, that this data is not a UTF-8 encoded string and `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` will just produce garbage.

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 36):

```
byte[] bytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexString);
String result= new String(bytes, encoding);
```

Comment: Where the heck do I find `DatatypeConverter`?

Comment: Not public anymore in recent Java versions

Comment: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

Comment: what are the encoding values?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Answer (score 13):

You can go from `String (hex)` to `byte array` to `String as UTF-8(?)`. *Make sure your hex string does not have leading spaces and stuff*.

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
    int l = hex.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[l / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Usage:

```
String b = "0xfd00000aa8660b5b010006acdc0100000101000100010000";
byte[] bytes = hexStringToByteArray(b);
String st = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(st);
```

Comment: how to do ot for versions below kitkat?

Comment: may I ask what is the purpose of converting it to String as UTF-8?

Answer (score 10):

First of all read in the data, then convert it to byte array:

```
 byte b = Byte.parseByte(str, 16);
```

and then use `String` constructor:

```
new String(byte[] bytes)
```

or if the charset is not system default then:

```
new String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)
```

Comment: Of course, it may or may not work depending on encoding used by "some other guys". Maybe they used Latin-9. Or UTF-8. Or EUC-JP. Or maybe it was in Big-Endian. Who knows?

Comment: That's why you should specify the encoding which was used by log strings before conversion to hex string.

Comment: use `Byte.parseByte(str, 16);` to parse a hexadecimal number.

Comment: The String constructor expects a byte array and not just byte, I tried and it failed.

Comment: @Callforeach yes it it exactly what I gave as en example, byte[] stands for array not single byte: new String(byte[] bytes)

Comment: I'm not following... where did you get the `bytes` byte array from?

Comment: @zundi in first line you parse only single byte. So you need to use a loop to get all the bytes and put them in array. Please look  at Munene iUwej Julius answer. His method is doing just that

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code:

```
public static byte[] decode(String hex){

        String[] list=hex.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
        ByteBuffer buffer= ByteBuffer.allocate(list.length);
        System.out.println(list.length);
        for(String str: list)
            buffer.put(Byte.parseByte(str,16));

        return buffer.array();

}
```

To convert to String just create a new String with the byte[] returned by the decode method.

Comment: I changed Byte.parseByte to (byte)Integer.parseInteger to allow for numbers > 128 to be parsed.

Comment: @domenukk it's Integer.parseInt(..) not Integer.parseInteger(..) . Byte.parseByte implemented as follow { return (byte) Integer.parseInt(Str, base);}

Comment: @Munene thanx 4 regex

Answer (score 6):

Just another way to convert hex string to java string:

```
public static String unHex(String arg) {        

    String str = "";
    for(int i=0;i<arg.length();i+=2)
    {
        String s = arg.substring(i, (i + 2));
        int decimal = Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
        str = str + (char) decimal;
    }       
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Lots of substrings being created. Not ideal.

Comment: replace "String str" with a StringBuffer(), and use sb.append(char) if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 6):

There is yet another way to do this if using JDK17 or above, see the new  [HexFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html#parseHex(java.lang.CharSequence)) class which has useful methods for converting `byte[]` <=> hexadecimal `String` :

```
String hexStr ="5468697320697320616e206578616d706c6520737472696e67";
byte[] bytes = HexFormat.of().parseHex(hexStr);
String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 /* or Charset.forName("whateverencoding")*/);
```

You of course need to know the exact character encoding of the hexadecimal representation in order to generate the correct `String` value.