# Jenkins IllegalArgumentException while adding a new agent

Tags: jenkins, illegalargumentexception, jenkins-agent

I want to add a new agent to Jenkins. When I followed the Jenkins UI, it gives me the command below

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://<jenkins_url>/computer/<slave_name>/slave-agent.jnlp -secret <REDACTED>
```

When I tried to execute that command, its output like below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IV buffer too short for given offset/length combination
        at javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec.<init>(IvParameterSpec.java:80)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:515)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:325)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:283)
```

Could you please help me about this error? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603153/illegalargumentexception-iv-buffer-too-short-for-given-offset-length-combinatio

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the setting of the IV length in Jenkins code as well as in the Jenkins agents code (remoting) and it seems to be consistently set to 16 bytes everywhere.

*However*, by running `curl` to GET the slave-agent.jnlp URL (`$JENKINS_URL/computer/$node_name/slave-agent.jnlp`), I found that the http:// URL which I thought I should be using returns just "302 Found" with the "location" header set to the same URL but with https://. `curl`ing that, I saw messages about missing permissions in Jenkins (to Read, then to Connect agents). Adding those for anonymous users (at `$JENKINS_URL/configureSecurity`, using matrix-based security) resolved that issue for me.

Or rather, it turned it into another issue, which was "Connection refused". It took me another while to figure out that -- for our Jenkins master running in a container -- in the Global Security configuration, "TCP port for inbound agents" must be set to the container-internal port, while in the node configuration, "Tunnel connection through" has to be set to the external port.

I hope my debugging exercise will be at least partially applicable in your context, too.

Comment: I forgot to add that the errors result in this particular message because when Jenkins (master, I think) is expecting 16 bytes of payload -- the IV --, the connection doesn't work out and it ends up receiving -- presumably -- 0 bytes. (...resulting in a byte array of that length here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/remoting/blob/remoting-4.2/src/main/java/hudson/remoting/Launcher.java#L527 .)

Answer (score 0):

For me this exact error was caused because meanwhile I moved from http to https with Jenkins and added startup parameter --httpsRedirectHttp to the startup of Java service (I am running on windows). That caused problems which were solved by modifying system property "Jenkins URL" on the main node to include "https://" instead of previous "http://".

After that I've downloaded the new agent.jar on my node and run it as it was stated in the instructions and it worked flawlessly. Hope that helps .