# Convert Hexadecimal to String

Tags: java, string, numbers, hex

To convert String to Hexadecimal i am using:

```
public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}
```

This is outlined in the top-voted answer here:
[Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java)

*How do i do the reverse i.e Hexadecimal to String?*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990941/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-java-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reconstruct `bytes[]` from the converted string,
here's one way to do it:

```
public String fromHex(String hex) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    hex = hex.replaceAll("^(00)+", "");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
        bytes[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return new String(bytes);
}
```

Another way is using `DatatypeConverter`, from `javax.xml.bind` package:

```
public String fromHex(String hex) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    hex = hex.replaceAll("^(00)+", "");
    byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hex);
    return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
}
```

Unit tests to verify:

```
@Test
public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String[] samples = {
            "hello",
            "all your base now belongs to us, welcome our machine overlords"
    };
    for (String sample : samples) {
        assertEquals(sample, fromHex(toHex(sample)));
    }
}
```

Note: the stripping of leading `00` in `fromHex` is only necessary because of the `"%040x"` padding in your `toHex` method.
If you don't mind replacing that with a simple `%x`,
then you could drop this line in `fromHex`:

> ```
>     hex = hex.replaceAll("^(00)+", "");
> ```

Comment: That works perfectly...is there anyway to do this (Hex to String) using String.format/BigInteger (the way it is done for StringToHex) part?

Comment: Not with String.format/BigInteger, but using DatatypeConverter (updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
String hexString = toHex("abc");
System.out.println(hexString);
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexString);
System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
```

output:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000616263
abc
```