# Getting no seeders and leechers for scrape from udp tracker

Tags: java, udp, bittorrent

I am trying to implement the scrape method for an UDP tracker but I keep getting 0 seeders/leechers as response. I am still getting a 2 as the action so no error is reported. 
I have hardcoded a hash here just to show that it has no effect on the result I am getting.

```
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream =new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final DataOutputStream dataStream =new DataOutputStream(byteStream);
    dataStream.writeInt(connectResponse.get("connectionId0"));
    dataStream.writeInt(connectResponse.get("connectionId1"));
    dataStream.writeInt(2);
    dataStream.write(connectResponse.get("transactionId"));
    bencodeWriter.write(byteOut.toString());
    dataStream.writeChars("1D19CC96C1A4965D184E4B215942DBC0A09FF8F2");
    dataStream.close();
    final byte[] scrapeBytes= byteStream.toByteArray();
```

I tried different trackers but get the same response. What might be the problem?

Edit: Added the hex dump of all the requests and responses:

Connect Request:
[image: Connect request]

Connect Response:
[image: Connect response]

Scrape Request:
[image: Scrape request]

Scrape Response:
[image: Scrape response]

Comment: What exactly are you sending and  receiving on the wire? Could you possibly use Wireshark and post a HEX+ASCII dump.

Comment: I am sending a DatagramPacket the bytes above. I am not sure what you mean by HEX+ASCII dumps. Should I capture the transmissions as normal?

Comment: Added it to my post.

Comment: Good, but I need to see the full conversation. I.E. Connect request, Connect response, Scrape request and Scrape  response

Comment: Ok, edited it again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Scrape request;
the `transaction_id`=`0x36` is sent as a single byte instead of 4 bytes=`0x00000036`
and the `info_hash` is sent as a 80 bytes string that is hex-encoded were every character is prepended by a zero-byte `0x00` instead of as a raw 20 bytes string.
I.E. `0x0031004400310039...` instead of `0x1D19...`

The Scrape response has no peers, as there is no torrents with the info_hashes sent in the request.

Comment: I had missed dataStream.write instead of dataStream.writeInt for the transaction_id so that fixes that. Do you have any suggestion on how to get the hash into the right format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990941/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-java-string or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806404/convert-hexadecimal-to-string ?! I don't Java.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Got it to work with the apache commons hex when having the string but still wondering how to do it with a an info hashmap. Maybe I'll start another question if I don't figure it out...

Comment: Hehe, tack! :-)