# Unicode characters not displayed properly in JButtons

Tags: java

I used this statement to set text of `JButtons`:

```
buttons[i][j].setText(""+(char)hex);
```

where `buttons[][]` is a `JButton Array,`
`hex` is int and ranges from `0x0980` to 128 more

`++hex;` is used to increment.
Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH5eG.png).

Comment: Unless you say what system you use, what is its current police, and what characters are correctly displayed and what ones are not, I cannot help you.

Comment: I am currently running Windows-7 Ultimate 32-bit architecture.

Comment: A look at the screenshot will reveal that not all characters are causing problems. Some are indeed being displayed as they should.

Comment: It is probably a problem with fonts.  Have you installed the appropriate fonts on your Windows machine?

Comment: What are the required fonts?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running into the issue of properly converting your hex values to strings. Take a look at [Convert Hexadecimal to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806404/convert-hexadecimal-to-string) and see if using a solution from there will help.