# How can I print directly a number as a string?

Tags: c, string, stdout

```
printf("%s", 0x216f6c6c6548); // "Hello!" reversed
```

It should print "Hello!" but it doesn't. I expected the same result of:

```
long long ll = 0x216f6c6c6548;
printf("%s", &ll);
```

or

```
printf("%s", "Hello!");
```

Is it possible to print a number as a string?

**UPDATE**

Is it possible to print **directly** a number as a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert hex string to java string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990941/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-java-string)

Comment: It sounds like you need to extract each byte from the numerical value and then treat each byte as a character.

Comment: @Aaditya Gavandalkar I don't know Java at the moment.

Comment: I tried your code `printf("%s", &ll);` on OS X and it prints `Hello!` (no new line).

Comment: It didn't have to print newline.

Comment: Of course it wouldn't work, because `%s` expects a pointer, not a number.

Comment: I had thought that but nor "Hello!" is a pointer, it doesn't refer to a memory address.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: `long long ll = 0x216f6c6c6548; printf("%s", &ll);` is a problem given 1) endian byte order 2) lack of strict adherence to pointer type 3) in general, a `long long` may not contain a null character. `printf("%.8s", (char*) &ll)` is a little better.

Comment: Why endian byte order is a problem (little endian)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to extract the characters from the number:

```
print_ull_as_str (unsigned long long ll)
{
    while (ll != 0) { printf("%c", (char )(ll & 0xffu)); ll >>= 8; }
}
```

Comment: Therefore there aren't any ways to print the number without using a variable. Am I right?

Comment: @Simone Bonato: Right.

Answer (score 2):

After accept answer

Easy to print **directly**.  Use a compound literal to form the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SBprint(x) ((char [8+1]){ \
    1ULL*x>>0 , 1ULL*x>> 8, 1ULL*x>>16, 1ULL*x>>24, \
    1ULL*x>>32, 1ULL*x>>40, 1ULL*x>>48, 1ULL*x>>56, 0})


int main(void) {
  printf("%s", SBprint(0x216f6c6c6548));
  printf("%s", SBprint(0x65726120776F480A));
  printf("%s", SBprint(0x0A3F756F7920));
}
```

Output

```
Hello!
How are you?
```

If your compiler use little endian, even simpler.

```
#define SBprint(x) ((union {long long ll[2]; char s[sizeof(long long)+1]; }){ {x, 0} }).s
```

Comment: Relative to first code (very illuminating), I think it isn't the true output, beacuse of carriage return (and there isn't newline). Correct?

Comment: Relative to the second one, after the cast to union, what does `{ {x, 0} }` mean?

Comment: @Simone Bonato Incorrect - it is the true output. `stdout` is typically in "text mode".  That will translate the `'\n'`or `0D` that was sent by `printf()`  to do whatever is appropriate for the console end-of-line.  In this case the output screen experienced a cursor re-positioning to the beginning of the next line (carriage Return / Line Feed).

Comment: @Simone Bonato There is no "cast to union". Think of  `printf("Hello");`  `"Hello"` is a string literal.  This code creates a _compound literal_ of type `union {long long ll[2]; char s[sizeof(long long)+1]; }`.  The  `{x, 0}` populates that literal with `x` and `0`.  Then when that literal's field `.s` is passed to `printf()`, it is converted to the address of  first element of the array `.s[0]`, which happens to contain the least significant byte of `x` stored in it.

Comment: So `printf()` receives the address to the first byte of an array.  The array  contains `'H'`,`'e'`,`l'`, ....   In case the most-significant-byte of `x` was non-zero, the `0` of `{x, 0}` insures a whole lot of null characters follow and so the array of characters contain a null character, thus making the array a _string_.

Comment: IMO, code _can_ "print the number without using a variable".  This code just uses literals.

Comment: But can 0 be omitted? If I have `typedef union{
    int i;
    char ch;
}U;` and `printf("%c",(U){0x41, 0}.i);` is it considered cast or compound literal? (I'm a bit off topic, sorry)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102036/discussion-between-chux-and-simone-bonato).

Comment: Aren't there any overflows?

Comment: @Simone Bonato Use `unsigned char [9]` instead of `char [8+1]` to quell overflow concerns.