# java method for decoding via unicode_escape

Tags: java, python, parsing, string-decoding

Python has a nice function to decode hex and unicode characters in Strings, like so:

```
print "123\x20Fake\x20St\u002e".decode('unicode_escape')
```

Will print:

```
123 Fake St.
```

Is there anything similar in java, or is this something that has to be handled with regexes?

**EDIT 1**

I believe my question is different than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990941/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-java-string) as it looks like that question is asking to decode a hex only String. Mine is mixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert hex string to java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990941/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-java-string)

Comment: Java supports the last form. No decode necessary. `System.out.println("\u002e");` prints "."

Comment: Note, in Python 2, you'd just use `u"123\x20Fake\x20St\u002e"` instead of `decode` to write a unicode literal. In Python 3, the literal `"123\x20Fake\x20St\u002e"` would be interpreted as a unicode literal by default (the `str` type being equivalent to Python 2 `unicode` type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to use that string you would receive an error since `\x` is not a [valid scape character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters). You can use either the unicode form that would be replacing `\x` by `\u00` or the octal form, without any previous character.

Unicode:

```
System.out.println("123\u0020Fake\u0020St\u002e"); // 123 Fake St.
```

Octal (20 hex to octal is 40):

```
System.out.println("123\40Fake\40St\u002e"); // 123 Fake St.
```

---

By the other hand, if you have the string scaped.

```
String scaped = "123\\x20Fake\\x20St\\u002e";
```

Which in java is the literal `123\x20Fake\x20St\u002e`.

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters) to transform the scaped unicodes characters, but you have to handle the hex first, and you can do it replacing the `\x` with `\u00` like mentioned before:

```
scaped.replaceAll("\\\\x", "\\\\u00")
```

And then use any of the methods mentioned in the answer above to transform the unicode scaped string. Using apache `commons-text` would be something like:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("123\\x20Fake\\x20St\\u002e"
        .replaceAll("\\\\x", "\\\\u00")) // 123 Fake St.
```