# String hash vs Binary Hash in Java

Tags: java, hash, bitcoin

I am writing a Java program that converts Bitcoin privateKey to WIF format.
Unfortunately, I got wrong SHA256 hashes.

My code is based on Basing on [this tutorial](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format).

When I hash a value like:

```
800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D
```

I get something like this as result:

```
e2e4146a36e9c455cf95a4f259f162c353cd419cc3fd0e69ae36d7d1b6cd2c09
```

instead of:

```
8147786C4D15106333BF278D71DADAF1079EF2D2440A4DDE37D747DED5403592
```

This is my piece of code:

```
public String getSHA(String value){
    String hash = hash = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(value.getBytes());
    System.out.println(hash);
    return hash;
}
```

I used this library: `import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;`

Of course I searched this problem on the web and I found [this site](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?hex=800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D).

On that website, there are two textboxes - String hash and Binary Hash.
Using a String hash, I got the same incorrect result as in my Java program.
But, using a Binary hash, I got a right result.

My question is: 
What is the difference between Binary and String hashes?
How to implement Binary hash in my Java method?

Comment: Probably you are using 800C28... as a String but it should be the byte array 0x80,0x0C,0x28,...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `800C28...` is a text representation of `byte[]` using hex encoding. To convert it back to `byte[]` you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36417192/1602555), one way would be to do it is:

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
  int l = hex.length();
  byte[] data = new byte[l/2];
  for (int i = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
    data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
      + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i+1), 16));
  }
  return data;
}
```

`String.getBytes()` will return the character values, e.g. character `8` has a value of 56 as per [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("8".getBytes())); // 56
```