# How to split and convert a hexstring?

Tags: python, integer, hex

I have to take a hex string and convert it.

ex. I get this string `1101222233334444555500206666666677777777889900200012ff1f4412ff1f3720030057010000`.

I have to split it up to this `11 01 22 22 33 33 44 44 55 55 00 20 66 66 66 66 77 77 77 77 88 99 00 20 00 12 ff 1f 44 12 ff 1f 37 20 03 00 57 01 00 00` and convert it.

**Edit:** It is from hex to decimal.

Comment: Do you have to chunk it by 2?

Comment: Convert it to what?

Comment: @Mureinik hexidecimal number I think. Like 0xFFFFFF

Comment: It already looks like a hex number. What am I missing?

Comment: @Mureinik maybe back into a base 10 integer?

Comment: Example with java, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990941/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-java-string

Answer (score 2):

There are a few lesser known methods of `bytes` objects:

```py
>>> s='1101222233334444555500206666666677777777889900200012ff1f4412ff1f3720030057010000'
>>> bytes.fromhex(s)  # gives a byte string
b'\x11\x01""33DDUU\x00 ffffwwww\x88\x99\x00 \x00\x12\xff\x1fD\x12\xff\x1f7 \x03\x00W\x01\x00\x00'
```

As bytes you can get the individual values of each byte, or convert the whole thing to a list:

```py
>>> b=bytes.fromhex(s)
>>> b[0]
17
>>> b[1]
1
>>> list(b)
[17, 1, 34, 34, 51, 51, 68, 68, 85, 85, 0, 32, 102, 102, 102, 102, 119, 119, 119, 119, 136, 153, 0, 32, 0, 18, 255, 31, 68, 18, 255, 31, 55, 32, 3, 0, 87, 1, 0, 0]
```

And can convert back:

```py
>>> b.hex()  # converts back to a hex string
'1101222233334444555500206666666677777777889900200012ff1f4412ff1f3720030057010000'
>>> b.hex(sep=' ')  # adds a separator
'11 01 22 22 33 33 44 44 55 55 00 20 66 66 66 66 77 77 77 77 88 99 00 20 00 12 ff 1f 44 12 ff 1f 37 20 03 00 57 01 00 00'
```